# cx_Freeze cannot find libicuuc.so.56 and libQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration.so.5

Tags: ubuntu, pyqt, qt5, cx-freeze, icu

I'm trying to freeze and package a PyQt5 app on Ubuntu 16.04.02 into an exe file, but cx_Freeze reports that it can't find `libicuuc.so.56`, `libicudata.so.56` and `libQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration.so.5`.

When I search for the icu files on my system, I find that version 55 is currently installed.

```
$ apt-cache search libicu
icu-devtools - Development utilities for International Components for Unicode
libicu-dev - Development files for International Components for Unicode
libicu55 - International Components for Unicode
libicu55-dbg - International Components for Unicode
libicu4j-4.4-java - Library for Unicode support and internationalization
libicu4j-49-java - Library for Unicode support and internationalization
libicu4j-java - Library for Unicode support and internationalization
```

Seems like I need to upgrade icu or find a copy of the files in question to cx_Freeze. How?

Also, how do I solve the `libQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration.so.5` problem?

I've upgraded PyQt5, cx_Freeze, pip, and sip to the most recent versions with no improvement.

Thanks very much

Comment: have you tried pyinstaller? It solved all my problems with qt.

Comment: @Skandix Wow. Pyinstaller is so much easier that cx_freeze. Pyinstaller packaged my app perfectly on Ubuntu 16.04.02.  No problems with missing dependencies, no extra steps of creating a setup.py file, etc. I'm very happy with the results.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped - close or even delete your question when your done